# The getter 'sliders' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: sliders

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

!!!
In the homeslider.dart widget, the slider does not appear (null) and the initstate does not work. + When I comment the HomeSliderWidget in the homepage.dart file, the screen opens without the slider.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#7bbd3](state: RawGestureDetectorState#c53b1(gestures: , behavior: opaque)):
The getter 'sliders' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: sliders

```
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  SingleChildScrollView SingleChildScrollView:file:///Users/ddo/Desktop/projects/Version3/GedikKaynak-App/lib/views/screens/home_page/home_page.dart:168:22
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
 #1      StorySliderController.slider_items (package:gedik_holding/core/controller/story_slider_controller.dart:21:46)
                     #2      _HomeSliderWidgetState.initState (package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/home_slider.dart:37:27)
                     #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4942:57)
                     #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
                     #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
                     #6      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6350:36)
                     #7      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6362:32)
                     ...     Normal element mounting (80 frames)
```

home_slider.dart

```
// Dart imports:
import 'dart:convert';

// Flutter imports:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

// Project imports:
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/constants/services_url_const.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/controller/story_slider_controller.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/models/categories_list_model.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/models/story_slider_model.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/category/categories.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/product_detail/product_detail.dart';

class HomeSliderWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeSliderWidgetState createState() => _HomeSliderWidgetState();
}

class _HomeSliderWidgetState extends State<HomeSliderWidget> {
  var _current = 0;
  StorySliderController controller;
  List snapshot;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller = Get.put(StorySliderController());
    snapshot = controller.slider_items();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    snapshot = controller.slider_items();
    //print('snapshot length: ${snapshot.length}');
    /*
    for(int i =0; i<snapshot.length; i++){
      print(snapshot[i].link);
      print('category');
      print(snapshot[i].isCategory);
      print(snapshot[i].featurePhoto);
      print('--');
      snapshot[i].isCategory == 0;

    }*/

    /*
    Stream documentStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products')
        .doc("${widget.product}${Get.locale.languageCode.toString()}")
        .snapshots();
    print(documentStream);
    */

    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          GetBuilder(
            init: Get.put(StorySliderController()),
            builder: (_) => CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    /*
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Dialog(
                      elevation: 0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*.6,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*.8,
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: Text("Bekleyiniz")
                      ),

                    );
                  },
                  );
                  */
                    snapshot[index].link != ""
                        ? snapshot[index].isCategory == 0
                            ? Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProductDetail(snapshot[index].link)))
                            : goCategory().then((value) {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          CategoriesPage(value,index: value.data.allCategories
                                              .firstWhere((element) => element.parentId == null)
                                              .id,),
                                    ));
                              })
                        : null;
                  },
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                        child: ColorFiltered(
                          child: Image.network(
                            snapshot[index].featurePhoto,
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          ),
                          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                            Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                            BlendMode.dstATop,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      snapshot[index].link != ""
                          ? Positioned(
                              top: 5,
                              right: 0,
                              child: Icon(Icons.touch_app_outlined))
                          : Container(),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                  autoPlay: true,
                  onPageChanged: (index, a) {
                    _current = index;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  aspectRatio: 1.7,
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.scale),
            ),
          ),
          /*  FutureBuilder(
              future: controller.items,
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<StorySliderModel> snapshot){
            return snapshot.hasData ?          CarouselSlider.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.data.sliders.length,
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    snapshot.data.data.sliders[index].link!=""?
                    snapshot.data.data.sliders[index].isCategory==0?
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>ProductDetail(snapshot.data.data.sliders[index].link))):submit1().then((value) {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => CategoriesPage(value),
                          ));
                    }):null;
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: ColorFiltered(
                      child: Image.network(
                        snapshot.data.data.sliders[index].featurePhoto,
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      ),
                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        Colors.white.withOpacity(1),
                        BlendMode.dstATop,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              options: CarouselOptions(
                  autoPlay: true,
                  onPageChanged: (index, a) {
                    _current = index;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  aspectRatio: 1.70,
                  viewportFraction: 1,
                  enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.scale),
            ):Container();

          })*/
          /* Positioned(
                            bottom:50,
                            right: 200,

                            left: 200,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 8,
                              height:50,
                              child: ListView.builder(

                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  itemCount: 4,

                                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                                    return  Container(
                                      width: 8.0,
                                      height: 8.0,
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 2.0),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                          color: _current == index
                                              ? Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.9)
                                              : Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),*/
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

home_page.dart

```
// Dart imports:
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/controller/connection_controller.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/packages/feedback/feedback.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Img;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

// Project imports:
import 'package:gedik_holding/core/controller/login_controller.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/portal/home/portal_home_screen.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/help_desk/tawkto_page.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/category_widget.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/featured_products.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/go_calculator_page.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/go_certificate_page.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/home_slider.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/new_products.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/search_bar.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/shortcuts_slider.dart';
import 'package:gedik_holding/views/screens/home_page/widgets/story_widget.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: HomeDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          toolbarHeight: 40,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            /* IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.error,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
                onPressed: () => BetterFeedback.of(context).show((UserFeedback feedback) {

                  print(feedback);
                })

             ),*/
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.comment,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HelpDesk()))),
            /*Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional(-1.0, -0.8),
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          context,f
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CartPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite_border,
                        color: Colors.black26,
                      )),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 0,
                    child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: Hive.box("cart").listenable(),
                        builder: (context, snap, _) {
                          return CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 10.0,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            child: Text(
                              Hive.box("cart").values.length.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13.0),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )*/
          ],
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Get.put(LoginController()).isLogged
                  ? IconButton(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Get.to(PortalHomePage());
                      },
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.transform,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    )
                  : Container(),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  /* Navigator.push(
                      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DevPage()));*/
                },
                child: Image.asset(
                  Get.locale.languageCode == "tr" || Get.locale.languageCode == "az"
                      ? "assets/images/gedikkaynak_logo.png"
                      : "assets/images/gedikwelding_logo.png",
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          /*Positioned(
            top: 50,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Center(child: Container(child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Yenileniyor"),
                RefreshProgressIndicator()
              ],
            ),)),
          ),*/
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 50),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SearchBarWidget(),
                    Get.put(ConnectionController()).remoteConfig != null
                        ? Get.locale.languageCode == "tr" && Get.put(ConnectionController()).remoteConfig.getBool("is_story")
                            ? StoryWidget()
                            : Container()
                        : Container(),
                    HomeSliderWidget(),
                    ShortCutsSlider(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    HomeShopByCategory(),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    GoCalculatorPageButton(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    //FeaturedProducts(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    GoCertificatePageButton(),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    //NewProducts(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: help me @eamirho3ein

Comment: where this error happend?

Comment: In the homeslider.dart widget, the slider does not appear (null) and the initstate does not work. + When I comment the HomeSliderWidget in the homepage.dart file, the screen opens without the slider.